# Converting String to Date Without Time?

Tags: ruby, date

This should be so simple but I'm missing something.

I get an invalid date when trying to convert a string to a Date.

```
irb(main):076:0> current_date
=> "December 21, 2022 04.00 AM"
irb(main):077:0> current_date.class
=> String
irb(main):078:0> date_format
=> "%M %e, %Y"
irb(main):079:0> date_format_time
=> "%M %e, %Y %l.%i %p"
irb(main):080:0> new_date = Date.strptime(current_date, date_format).iso8601
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):80
        1: from (irb):80:in `strptime'
Date::Error (invalid date)
irb(main):081:0> new_date = Date.strptime(current_date, date_format_time).iso8601
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):80
        2: from (irb):81:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        1: from (irb):81:in `strptime'
Date::Error (invalid date)
```

I'm trying to convert the date into a string in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but I've definitely used Date.strptime to convert a date with a time to a date. Example below: 

irb(main):089:0> date_example = 'Dec 21, 2022 01:18 PM'
=> "Dec 21, 2022 01:18 PM"
irb(main):090:0> date_format = '%b %d, %Y'
=> "%b %d, %Y"
irb(main):091:0> converted = Date.strptime(date_example, date_format).iso8601
=> "2022-12-21"

I guess I'm having trouble understangind how this differs?

Comment: This `%M` is the directive for minutes not the directive for full month name, which is why you are receiving the `Date::Error`. You need `%B` instead. [`Date#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date_format_time` doesn't feel right. Try this instead:

```
current_date = "December 21, 2022 04.00 AM"
date_format_time = "%B %e, %Y %I.%M %p"

Date.strptime(current_date, date_format_time).iso8601
#=> "2022-12-21"
```

Btw. I suggest http://strftime.net/ to play around and analyze with strptime's format codes.